# Thread state TIMED_WAITING, increasing in every execution and remaining alive-true

Tags: java, hibernate, c3p0

I am using hibernate 4.1.9 on Oracle DB, used jars `hibernate-c3p0-4.1.9.Final.jar`, `hibernate-core-4.1.9.Final.jar`, `c3p0-0.9.1.2.jar`.

c3p0 configuration like below...

```
    <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property> <!-- hibernate 4.1.9 -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireIncrement">3</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTime">3600</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.minPoolSize">6</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxPoolSize">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxStatements">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod">1800</property> <!-- seconds -->
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxConnectionAge">50</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.maxIdleTimeExcessConnections">300</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1 from dual</property>

    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCachingRegionFactory</property>
```

Increasing thread like below....

(It has been printed by a loop... by `System.out.println("<br/>" + c++ +". "+ t.getState() + " (" + t.isAlive() + ") : " + t.getName());`)

Output...

```
    4066. TIMED_WAITING (true) : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1
    4067. TIMED_WAITING (true) : Timer-203
    4068. TIMED_WAITING (true) : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0
    4069. TIMED_WAITING (true) : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0
    4070. TIMED_WAITING (true) : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0
    2071. TIMED_WAITING (true) : com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1
```

These thousands of thread just increasing and remains in the same state. How to remove them ?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47326398/1413240

Comment: Yes this is duplicate @Steve